# how to implement Timer functionality in Apigee

Tags: apigee

I want to generate access tokens every 15 minutes . Is there a way to implement it using timers?

Or say if i want to invoke a service every x minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As of now the platform does not provide a way to run batch jobs. But any scheduler from outside can be used to invoke an API exposed by the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can set each access token to expire in 15 minutes.  If an application using the token makes a request after the token has expired you can return a 401 or 403 status code, and ask developers to create a new token at that time by calling the token endpoint again.

If you *really* want to generate tokens in batches and store them for later use, create a script that invokes "curl" or your favorite HTTP client to call your token endpoint to generate the desired number of tokens.